# 'list' attribute has no attribute <function>

Tags: python

I am trying to create a class for Complex numbers that includes functions that operate on lists. I think my basic setup is okay because it works for functions that operate on single elements(like conjugate), but when I try to run functions like conjugateList, I get the error message "'list' object has no attribute 'conjugateList'. I am not sure how to address this problem. Thanks.

```
class Complex():
    def __init__(self, real= 0.0, imaginary= 0.0):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary = imaginary

    def __str__(self):
        if self.imaginary < 0:
            printStr = str(self.real) + ' - ' + str(abs(self.imaginary))+ 'i'
        else:
            printStr = str(self.real) + ' + ' + str(self.imaginary)+ 'i'
        return printStr

    def conjugate(self):
        result = Complex()
        result.real = self.real
        result.imaginary = (self.imaginary * (-1))
        return result

    def conjugateList(lstC):
        newLst = []
        for elem in lstC:
        elem = elem.conjugate()
        newLst += elem
        return newLst
```

Comment: can you indent this properly?  the first three defs need to be tabbed in one level.

Comment: you defined `conjugateList` on your `Complex` class, but you're calling it on a list.  that can't work.  you can write a top-level function to handle lists, or write a `ComplexList` class, but you can't jam new methods onto `list`.

Comment: also fyi Python already has a complex type; try `(1+2j).conjugate()` in the repl  :)

Comment: Please don't fix the OP's indentation for him in Python questions. It can hide bugs where the problem is incorrect indentation.

Comment: Is `conjugateList` defined inside the class or outside it?

Comment: Please, post the **full** traceback of the error, possibly with a minimal *working* example that demonstrates how you are using that class.

Comment: Give us the full traceback and the **actual code** that you're using to get the error. What you've posted doesn't even run, not to mention that you never call the methods you're talking about, so it's difficult to reproduce what you're seeing...

Comment: You're aware that Python has a `complex` type already? And that you can use it in `numpy` if you want to deal with arrays of them by specifing a `dtype=complex_` ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `conjugateList` method isn't on your list, it's on the `Complex` object.

Note that this `conjugateList` method should actually be a `staticmethod` or — better yet — a function.

You would do:

```
class Complex():    
    # The rest of your stuff

    @staticmethod
    def conjugateList(lstC):
        newLst = []
        for elem in lstC:
            elem = elem.conjugate()
            newLst += elem
        return newLst
```

And then,

```
l1 = [Complex(1,1), Complex(1,2)]
l2 = Complex.conjugateList(l1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short of learning purposes for class design, for production you might want to use `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> comps = np.array([complex(1, 1), complex(1, 2)])
>>> comps.dtype
dtype('complex128')
>>> comps.conjugate()
array([ 1.-1.j,  1.-2.j])
```